# How to get IDictionaryEnumerator from generic IDictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
  IDictionary<string, string> dict;
```

How to create an enumerator that implements IDictionaryEnumerator (preferably using linq)?

Comment: this question has awesome answers; It needs more upvotes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Must be missing something here, what about:

```
IDictionary obsoleteDict = dict as IDictionary;
if (obsoleteDict == null)
{
 //Do something here...
}
else
{
 return obsoleteDict.GetEnumerator();
}
```

*(edit: yep, you have to cast it to the old non-generic interface)*

*edit2: see Pavel's comment below. A type implementing `IDictionary<K,V>` may or may not implement IDictionary (`Dictionary<K,V>` does while some implementations like WCF's MessageProperties do not) so the cast may not work.*

Comment: It returns IEnumerator<KeyValuePar<string, string>> which doesn't cast to IDictionaryEnumerator

Comment: You have to cast your dictionary to the non generic interface IDictionary before calling GetEnumerator, and you'll get an enumerator yielding DictionaryEntry.

Comment: Btw. Do you know where i can find available casts in .net. I can't find it in the msdn

Comment: This isn't a good general approach, because there's no guarantee that a particular implementation of `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` also implements non-generic `IDictionary`. While `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements both, in the question itself, the variable is specifically declared as `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, which implies that other implementations are possible.

Comment: @Pavel Yep, you're right. LinkedDictionary<K,V> does not for instance. I'm nuking my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`IDictionaryEnumerator` is really the pre-generics version; you should just be able to use `IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`...

You could encapsulate, of course; this will then work even for custom implementations:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
static class Program
{
    class MyEnumerator<TKey,TValue> : IDictionaryEnumerator, IDisposable
    {
        readonly IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> impl;
        public void Dispose() { impl.Dispose(); }
        public MyEnumerator(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> value)
        {
            this.impl = value.GetEnumerator();
        }
        public void Reset() { impl.Reset(); }
        public bool MoveNext() { return impl.MoveNext(); }
        public DictionaryEntry Entry { get { var pair = impl.Current;
            return new DictionaryEntry(pair.Key, pair.Value);} }
        public object Key { get { return impl.Current.Key; } }
        public object Value { get { return impl.Current.Value; } }
        public object Current {get {return Entry;}}
    }
    static IDictionaryEnumerator GetBasicEnumerator<TKey,TValue>(
        this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> data)
    {
        return new MyEnumerator<TKey, TValue>(data);
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        IDictionary<int, string> data = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            {1,"abc"}, {2,"def"}
        };
        IDictionaryEnumerator basic;
        using ((basic = data.GetBasicEnumerator()) as IDisposable)
        {
            while (basic.MoveNext())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(basic.Key + "=" + basic.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `as` to check for an existing implementation of `IDictionaryEnumerator`. If it returns null, *then* wrap the `IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `IDictionaryEnumerator` is only implemented by non-generic dictionary types. The generic dictionary classes expose `IEnumerator`.

Since generic dictionaries return strongly typed KeyValuePair items, the features of IDictionaryEnumerator seem redundant. You should try to adapt your code if possible to just use `IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<K,V>>`.

Comment: IDictionaryEnumerator is implemented by the enumerator types for most of the generic IDictionary types as well.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, this will work. Then ones where it doesn't will throw an exception.

```
return (IDictionaryEnumerator)dict.GetEnumerator();
```

At least the following BCL types return enumerators that implement IDictionaryEnumerator (these are the ones I checked):

- `Hashtable` (public API enforced)
- `Dictionary<T,K>` (public API enforced)
- `SortedList<T,K>` (not guaranteed by the public API, but the implementation does implement it)